# How can I center an image of arbitrary size without resizing to the browser width? (Crop outside window for wide images)

Tags: php, css

I want to center an image with unknown width and height in the browser window without any resizing. If the image is wider than the browser width, which I expect it to often be, I want to crop the image rather than resize it. There should not be a horizontal scrollbar.

CSS only solutions are preferred, but PHP is acceptable and JS less desirable but still welcome. Using background images is not ideal.

[image: Concept sketch of very wide image being cropped to different browser window widths, always with the central feature of the image located in the center of the screen]

This question is very similar and I would answer it if I could: [Resize browser width and cover photo must retain the center of cropped image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63646246/resize-browser-width-and-cover-photo-must-retain-the-center-of-cropped-image)

This code block gives a sense of what I've tried, but may not be very helpful:

```css
.banner-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /*height: 450px;*/
  /*
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle
  */
  /*justify-content: center;*/
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
  /*object-fit: cover;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container">
<img class="banner" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppDo7.png">
</div>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an img element which I see you prefer.

This snippet uses one of the methods you tried to center it - to get the left/right centering it moves the img to have the left as the center of the div, then moves it back by half its width.

It does not try centering vertically as the requirement seems to be to have the img height the full height of the banner, but this could of course be changed if wanted.

Note that to stop overflow being shown with a scrollbar the correct setting is overflow: hidden, not hide as in the given code.

```css
.banner-container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-container">
  <img class="banner" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppDo7.png">
</div>'
```

Comment: In my own code it actually did say `overflow: hidden;`, so I edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: In your snippet this works as expected, but on my website the image continues to resize, so there's probably some other styling that's affecting it.

Comment: Can you inspect using your browser dev tools to see exactly what styling is being applied?

Comment: I could not get `overflow` to work, but I saw that the Imagify WordPress plugin was wrapping images in <picture> tags. After eliminating that, `object-fit: cover;` worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, this is the CSS that worked in my situation:

```
.banner-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 450px;
}
.banner {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

As described in the comment to A Haworth's answer, Imagify was replacing `<img>` tags with `<picture>`, which interferes with the style structure. Since Imagify's optimizations are used in current posting habits and the conversion to `<picture>` is generally desired, I avoid the conversion simply by only using .webp images for this banner.

(This is for desktop. Smaller screens get different images and have modified behavior for better performance and appearance.)